# Remove quick view, add to basket and add to wish list hoover icons - woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to find a way to remove the three buttons that pop up when I hoover the product – quick view, add to wish list, add to basket. I have tried with the following code but it only removed the icons, text and the feature itself are still there.

CSS:

```
.related.products .yith-wcqv-button {
display: none;
}
```

php:

```
add_action( ‘template_redirect’, ‘yith_wcqv_remove_from_wishlist’ );
function yith_wcqv_remove_from_wishlist(){
if( function_exists( ‘YITH_WCQV_Frontend’ ) && defined(‘YITH_WCQV_FREE_INIT’) ) {
remove_action( ‘yith_wcwl_table_after_product_name’, array( YITH_WCQV_Frontend(), ‘yith_add_quick_view_button’ ), 15 );
}
}
```

The page I need help with: http://poshwish.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remove them by myself. Add the following piece of code to the theme css file and it does the magic:

```
.product_list_widget .quick-view{
  display: none;
}
.product-interactions {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the same customize menu:

yourwebsite.com/wp-admin -> Appearance -> Customize -> Woocommerce -> Product loop

and disabling all the Featured Icons